# What kubectl command can I use to get events sorted by specific fields and print only specific details of events?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I need to print only specific fields of Kubernetes Events, sorted by a specific field.

This is to help me gather telemetry and analytics about my namespace

How could I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310287/kubernetes-sort-pods-by-age/73614140 (my answer: `kubectl alpha events` https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614140/67824)

Answer (score 141):

`kubectl get events --sort-by='.lastTimestamp'`

Comment: in case this throws an error, try this `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`.

Answer (score 41):

> Following command does it.

It prints the events sorted by timestamp of creation.

It also users `go-template` to filter out specific fields of the `kubernetes-event` object.

```
kubectl get events  --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp'  -o 'go-template={{range .items}}{{.involvedObject.name}}{{"\t"}}{{.involvedObject.kind}}{{"\t"}}{{.message}}{{"\t"}}{{.reason}}{{"\t"}}{{.type}}{{"\t"}}{{.firstTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 13):

I am using the following command to sort it after timestamp

```
kubectl get event --all-namespaces --sort-by='.metadata.managedFields[0].time'
```

For filtering out the information you can of course combine it with the go-template described by @suryakrupa or with jq described by @Chris Stryczynski

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind seeing the output as JSON:

```
kubectl get event -o json | jq '.items |= sort_by(.lastTimestamp)'
```

This requires jq.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Bash function I use:

```sh
function kubectl-events {
    {
        echo $'TIME\tNAMESPACE\tTYPE\tREASON\tOBJECT\tSOURCE\tMESSAGE';
        kubectl get events -o json "$@" \
            | jq -r  '.items | map(. + {t: (.eventTime//.lastTimestamp)}) | sort_by(.t)[] | [.t, .metadata.namespace, .type, .reason, .involvedObject.kind + "/" + .involvedObject.name, .source.component + "," + (.source.host//"-"), .message] | @tsv';
    } \
        | column -s $'\t' -t \
        | less -S
}
```

You can use it like: `kubectl-events -A`, `kubectl-events -n foo`, etc.

Comment: But what is "oc" referring to?

Comment: Haha good question. `oc` is the OpenShift client that is basically `kubectl` + extra support for OpenShfit features. I am so used to typing it that I forgot to edit my answer to make it use `kubectl` instead.