# Kubernetes sort pods by age

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I can sort my Kubernetes pods by name using:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.name
```

How can I sort them (or other resoures) by age using `kubectl`?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Pods have status, which you can use to find out startTime.

I guess something like `kubectl get po --sort-by=.status.startTime` should work.

You could also try:

1. `kubectl get po --sort-by='{.firstTimestamp}'`.
2. `kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp` Thanks @chris

Also apparently in Kubernetes 1.7 release, sort-by is broken.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/43

Here's the bug report : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48602

Here's the PR: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/48659/files

Comment: @vjdhama is there a way to get a full list of things which can be sorted by in this way?

Comment: What do you mean by full list of things? You mean all types of resources.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse sort? So, for example, you can do a watch kubectl and get the newest pods at the top?

Comment: This does not seem to work? `error: couldn't find any field with path "{.status.startTime}" in the list of objects` - because the pods are still pending perhaps?

Comment: This only works if I also include the `-o json` or `-o wide` flags. Tested on 1.7.x and 1.9.x

Comment: @JoeJ The kubectl docs don't have a reverse order but you can do that with the tail command.
`kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | tail -r | head -n 1`
I used `tail -r` to revert the output. Then `head -n 1` to print the newest pod

Comment: The `.metadata.creationTimestamp` is a better choice as it includes the pending containers which naturally have zero `.status.startTime` and would therefore appear at the top of the list, not the bottom.

Comment: @Matthew, you may refer following URL for additional details (hope you already did, but it may help others):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#output-options

Answer (score 50):

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Comment: I'm getting `error: unknown type *api.Pod, expected unstructured in map[reflect.Type]*printers.handlerEntry{}` response

Comment: This is useful for sorting the **ConfigMaps**: 

`kubectl get cm --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to get the most recently created pod you can do the following

`kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o jsonpath='{.items[-1:].metadata.name}'`

Note the `-1:` gets the last item in the list, then we return the pod name

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort them in reverse order based on the age:

```
kubectl get po --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -n <<namespace>> | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

This new command (since Kubernetes 1.23) worked perfectly for me:

`kubectl alpha events`

In contrast, neither of these worked for me (got unsorted events):

- `kubectl get events --sort-by='.lastTimestamp'`
- `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`

I also saw reports that the above failed due to missing event properties: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29838#issuecomment-991070746

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the name of most-recently-created pod;

```
POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pod --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o name | cut -d/ -f2 | tail -n 1)
echo "${POD_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see all pods that were updated in the past 24 hours. This worked perfectly well and doesn't rely on a particular version of Kubernetes or Kubernetes advanced parameters besides get pods:

`kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1 " : " $5}' | grep -E ':\s([1-9]|[12][0-4])h$' | sort -k3,3`