# Get name of most recently created pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, jsonpath

In OpenShift, is there a more elegant way of obtaining the name of the most recently created pod in application `my_app` than this one?

```
name=$(oc get pods -l app=my_app -o=jsonpath='{range.items[*]}{.status.startTime}{"\t"}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | sort -r | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

The idea is to sort by `.status.startTime` and to output one `.metadata.name`. So far, I have not been successful in using `oc get` with both options `--sort-by` and `-o jsonpath` at the same time, so I have fallen back to Unix pipes in this version.

I am using OpenShift v3.9. I am also tagging this question for Kubernetes because it presumably applies to `kubectl` (instead of `oc`) in an analogous manner (without the `-l app=my_app`).

Comment: FWIW, you might also want to qualify based on status. ``oc get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Running")].metadata.name}'`` That way only shows when pod is actually running and not pods in other states.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}"
```

Comment: Thx. Works with `oc` as well.

Comment: This returns the results in reverse order, how do I get the most recent pod, not the oldest pod?

Comment: You can use jsonpath to get the last element in the result array. Instead of 0, use '-1:'

`kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o jsonpath="{.items[-1:].metadata.name}"`

Answer (score 4):

On Kubernetes front, `kubectl get po --sort-by=.status.startTime` is supposed to work, except in K8s 1.7: [it was fixed for 1.8](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/48659/commits/f1afc3d09d58fc9649b4dc9d8d3a5f46a9480cbd).

"[Kubernetes sort pods by age](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45310287/6309)" also mentions

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Since [Openshift 3.9](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v3.9.0) (March 2018) is fairly recent, those `kubectl` commands should work even if the `oc` one is not fully compatible.

Comment: Yes, but can `kubectl` return only the name of the one pod that it sorts last? For `oc get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp` I get a list of rows with columns `NAME`, `READY`, `STATUS`, `RESTARTS`,   `AGE`, sorted by age.